# How to build : Keyboard Input WDF Filter Driver (Kbfiltr)

Tags: keyboard, driver, sample, wdf

I tried to build the sample, but instructions in the readme file seems to be out of date. I tried with different versions of Visual Studio with no luck. The target is Win10 and the host is Win7. Are there up to date instructions somewhere ? What versions should I use ?